# How to show Android App widgets in a gridview, like the way we show all installed apps in phone

Tags: android, gridview, widget

I am new in Android development, with the help excellent tutorial from Leonardo Fischer (http://leonardofischer.com/hosting-android-widgets-my-appwidgethost-tutorial/), I have learned how to show a widget picker dialog and add respective picked widgets to my layout.

Is there an option where I can show the same widgets in a gridview like we see in some of the Android launchers?